# PHP 5.4 ON CENTOS 7 , NGINX , page not found error

Tags: centos, php, nginx

I am trying to install PHP 5.4  on CentOS 7

currently , my conf files look like the following :

/etc/nginx/conf.d

```
server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  178.62.255.79;

 root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
 index index.php index.html index.htm;

 location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }
 error_page 404 /404.html;
 error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
 location = /50x.html {
     root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri =404;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include fastcgi_params;
 } }
```

/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf is as default except

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

one thing to note is that when I looked into the directory /var/run/php-fpm/
there's a file named php-fpm.socks

the server can run http requests (nginx is working) , but when I try to browse a PHP file , it gives ,

> The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try
>   again later.

I followed many instructions , they all said that I should change 127.0.0.1:9000 to php-fpm.sock , but it is not working too

setting both conf files to 127.0.0.1:9000 is not working , I think the data is not being received by FastCGI Process Manager

do you know any of the available solutions ?

thanks

Comment: @Christopher , I am using /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock , not /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.socks

Answer (score 1):

check your /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf file and be sure to change the user and group from apache to nginx

```
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

then `systemctl restart  php-fpm.service` and see if that helps!